# Cannot execute prepared statement "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null" error

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

So I have this code

```
$lang=new language();
$default_language=$lang->getLanguage(0);

$currencies = new currency();
$currencies = $currencies->getCurrencies();
```

`getCurrencies()` and `getLanguage()` are in another file with classes.

```
public function getCurrencies() {
    $curr=new record();
    return $curr -> getRecords('currencyTable','currency_order',array("currency_id","currency_name"));
  }

public function getLanguage($record) {
    $lang=new record();
    return $lang->getRecord('languageTable',$record,'lang_order','*');
  }
```

And `getRecords` and `getRecord` are public functions it the `record` class

I keep on getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

Referring to the query of the `getRecords` functions.

I dont know how to fix this. Does this has to do with the connection to the database?

Also, the weird part is that if I remove the

```
$lang=new language();
$default_language=$lang->getLanguage(0);
```

part, this error goes away. Any help? Is the error in the `$default_language=$lang->getLanguage(0);` line and this is why it is messing up the database connection, resulting to this error?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here are the `getRecord` and `getRecords`

```
public function getRecords($table,$sorder,$field_names) {        
    $conn = db::open();

      //- build string of field names
      if($field_names!='*'){
      $field_string="";
      foreach ($field_names as $value) {
        $field_string.=",".$value;    
      }
      $field_string = substr($field_string,1);
    }else{
      $field_string='*';
    }
    //end up with field1, field2... or *
    //soreder is a field, contains int like 1 2 3

    //- run statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ".$field_string." FROM ".$table." ORDER BY ".$sorder." ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    return $results;
  }
```

and

```
public function getRecord($table,$record,$sorder,$field_names) {
    $conn = db::open();


      if($field_names!='*'){
      $field_string="";
      foreach ($field_names as $value) {
        $field_string.=",".$value;    
      }
      $field_string = substr($field_string,1);
    }else{
      $field_string='*';
       }
       //same things for $field_string and $sorder

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ".$field_string." FROM ".$table." ORDER BY ".$sorder." LIMIT ? OFFSET ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, 1 , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $record, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $results;
  }
```

I fixed an error. In `getRecord` I had  `LIMIT 1` and I fixed it as above. I still get the same error about the `getRecords` line : `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ".$field_string." FROM ".$table." ORDER BY ".$sorder." ASC");`

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Post the code for your `record` class.

Comment: your PDO connection failed, or you're not saving/accessing the PDO object properly, and are doing `$this->null->prepare` or whatever.

Comment: there is a problem with your db class.

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection failed. The error is not in your posted code. The error in your code is when the statement is being prepared. 
Ex: `$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table")`. I would recommend throwing an exception to see what's going wrong with your connection. You can do this by adding the options to your pdo initialization. `array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

```
  try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname='.MYSQL_DB,
                    MYSQL_USERNAME,
                    MYSQL_PASSWORD,
                    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
  }catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you want to check the update

Comment: Please [do not catch errors to report them](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors).